# JQuery DataTable responsive behavior not working for table inside Bootstrap 4 accordion

Tags: html, jquery, datatables, responsive

I have a Bootstrap 4 accordion with a table inside each section of it. The tables have the JQuery DataTables extension and are setup to be responsive. Before I put the tables in the accordion, the tables were behaving responsively (i.e. icons appear to expand/collapse rows, table resizes with window resize). But after moving them inside the accordion, the tables overflow and run off the screen instead of being responsive. I've tried every solution I've found so far, and nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }

        /*For centered headings*/
        .heading-center {
            margin-top: 3vh;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        /*Change color of focused elements' border*/
        .form-control:focus {
            border-color: #ffcc24 !important;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(255, 204, 36, 0.8) !important;
            outline: 0 none !important;
        }

        .form-control {
            border: none !important;
        }

        /*Override extra link decorations on navbar and home quick actions*/
        nav > ul > li > a:hover {
            text-decoration-line: none;
        }

        nav > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
            text-decoration-line: none;
        }

        .quick-actions a:hover {
            text-decoration-line: none;
        }

        /*Change background color of hovered table row*/
        .table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
            background-color: #ffcc24;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .table-text-center > tbody > tr > td,
        .table-text-center > thead > tr > th {
            text-align: center;
        }

        /*Override boostrap class attributes.*/
        .table .table-title th{
            background-color: black;
        }

        .table .table-title h1 {
            color: white;
        }

        .table .table-col-titles th{
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        /*.table {
            border-collapse: separate;
        }*/

        /*Sticky table header*/
        .sticky-title th{
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 60px;
        }

        .sticky-col-titles th {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 150px;
        }

        /* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
        .body-content {
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }

        /* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
        input,
        select,
        textarea {
            max-width: 280px;
        }

        /*Padding the nav bar*/
        .padded-nav {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        main {
        margin-top: 40px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    hr {
        display: block;
        height: 1px;
        border: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        margin: 1em 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .table {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    thead {
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .descr-table {
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        min-width: 250px;
    }

        .descr-table th {
            width: 30%;
            background-color: #ffcc24;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .descr-table td {
            width: 70%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="text-center">CUSTOMER DETAILS</h1>
    
        <table class="descr-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <td>98789098</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer Name</th>
                <td>Business, LLC</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
        <hr />
    
        <div class="accordion" id="customerDetailsAccordion">
    
            <div id="poTableHeader" class="collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#poTableWrapper" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="poTableWrapper">
                <h2 class="text-center">PURCHASE ORDERS</h2>
            </div>
    
            <div id="poTableWrapper" class="collapse container-fluid" aria-labelledby="poTableHeader" data-parent="#customerDetailsAccordion">
                <table id="poTable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-text-center">
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>234211</td>
                            <td>Products/Services P.O.</td>
                            <td>USD</td>
                            <td>11/20/2020</td>
                            <td>12/20/2021</td>
                            <td>$1000.00</td>
                            <td>$200.00</td>
                            <td>$100.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>234211</td>
                            <td>Products/Services P.O.</td>
                            <td>USD</td>
                            <td>11/20/2020</td>
                            <td>12/20/2021</td>
                            <td>$1000.00</td>
                            <td>$200.00</td>
                            <td>$100.00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>234211</td>
                            <td>Products/Services P.O.</td>
                            <td>USD</td>
                            <td>11/20/2020</td>
                            <td>12/20/2021</td>
                            <td>$1000.00</td>
                            <td>$200.00</td>
                            <td>$100.00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    
            <hr />
    
            <div id="userTableHeader" class="collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#userTableWrapper" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="userTableWrapper">
                <h2 class="text-center">USERS</h2>
            </div>
    
            <div id="userTableWrapper" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="userTableHeader" data-parent="#customerDetailsAccordion">
                <table id="usersTable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-text-center">
                    <thead></thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Mike Smith</td>
                            <td>smithm01</td>
                            <td>smithm01@tqs.com</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Mike Smith</td>
                            <td>smithm01</td>
                            <td>smithm01@tqs.com</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Mike Smith</td>
                            <td>smithm01</td>
                            <td>smithm01@tqs.com</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </main>

    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script defer src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.6/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

    <script defer>
        $("document").ready(function () {
            $("#poTable").DataTable({
                select: false,
                responsive: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        title: "PO #"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Service Type"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Currency"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Issue Date"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Expiration Date"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Total Amount"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Threshold Amount"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Remaining Amount"
                    }
                ]
            });
            
            $("#usersTable").DataTable({
                select: false,
                responsive: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        title: "Name"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Username"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Email"
                    }
                ]
            });
    
            //Redirect to po details page except when expand/collapse icon clicked.
            $('#poTable td').click(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('class') !== 'sorting_1')
                {
                    location.href = '#';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, that was fun! Quite the thing to do on a boring Sunday afternoon!

Anyway, you can't make something responsive when it's not visible. DataTables always has an issue with invisible tables - and the thing that got me stuck was figuring out how to listen to the shown event - I tried the native Bootstrap mechanism, but had no joy (I'll try some more though). In the meantime this method - using a couple of MutationObservers - seems to work a treat:

```
  const poNode = document.getElementById('poTableWrapper');
  const usersNode = document.getElementById('usersTable');
  const config = {
    attributes: true
  };
  const poCallback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
        $("#poTable").DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
      }
    }
  };
  const usersCallback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
    for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
        $("#usersTable").DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
      }
    }
  };
  const poObserver = new MutationObserver(poCallback);
  const usersObserver = new MutationObserver(usersCallback);
  poObserver.observe(poNode, config);
  usersObserver.observe(usersNode, config);
```

Working repl here: https://repl.it/@annoyingmouse/DearestCelebratedMultithreading#script.js (if it's useful, copy the code now, I'm not sure how long it'll last up there)

Comment: That works better, but for some reason it's adding DataTable to the table twice, so two sets of a "Show # Entries" and search bar are appearing. This is also causing the row expand/collapse not to expand/collapse the correct row.

Comment: Never mind, must have been a copying mistake. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Happy to help! Anything to take a break ;-) If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.